# Unable to replace implementation in a WebTestCase in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to replace the implementation of an autowirred service in a WebTestCase. For some reason, it is not getting replaced.

Here is the interface that I am looking to mock or replace the implementation.

```php
interface TimeServiceProvider
{
    public function now(): \DateTimeImmutable;
}
```

The runtime implementation:

```php
class TimeServiceProviderImpl implements TimeServiceProvider
{
    public function now(): \DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return new \DateTimeImmutable();
    }
}
```

services.yaml

```yaml
parameters:

services:
  # default configuration for services in *this* file
  _defaults:
    autowire: true # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
    autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    bind:
      $projectDir: '%kernel.project_dir%'
  # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
  # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
  App\:
    resource: "../src/"
    exclude:
      - "../src/DependencyInjection/"
      - "../src/Entity/"
      - "../src/Kernel.php"
```

The controller for which the service `TimeServiceProvider` get injected:

```php
class MyController extends AbstractController
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly TimeServiceProvider            $timeServiceProvider)
    {
    }

     #[Route('/api/test', name: 'test', methods: ['POST'])]
    public function test(
        #[MapRequestPayload(acceptFormat: 'json', validationGroups: ['strict', 'read'])] Command $command
    ): Response
    {
        $updated = $this->timeServiceProvider->now();
        // ...
        return $this->json(..., Response::HTTP_CREATED);
    }
```

The test:

```php
class IntegrationTest extends WebTestCase
{

    public function testSomething()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $container = $client->getContainer();
        $timeServiceProviderMock = $this->createMock(TimeServiceProvider::class);
        $timeServiceProviderMock
            ->expects(self::once())
            ->method("now")
            ->willReturn(
                new \DateTimeImmutable('2021-01-01 00:00:00')
            );
        $container->set(TimeServiceProvider::class, $timeServiceProviderMock);
        // http calls
```

When the test run, the date used is not the one from the mock but the one from the `TimeServiceProviderImpl`.

Note: I looked at the docs and tried to set the inteface at public but no luck

Any idea what's happening?